# How to export Firebase analytics data

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to export all the Firebase Analytics data to an excel spreadsheet, similar to how you can do it with Google Analytics. From what I can find the only way to go about doing it is to link with BigQuery then do some SQL statements to build a table and export.

Unfortunately for us this is not going to work (due to client budget and capabilities). Is there any other way to export this data that I'm missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update**: You can now export the analytics reports as CSV from the Firebase console by clicking the <kbd>Download CSV</kbd> option from the <kbd>⠇</kbd> overflow menu.

---

In the meantime, you really should give BigQuery another look.  The [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) is very reasonable and there is a free query tier of 1 TB/mo.

Steve Ganem

Product Manager, Firebase Analytics

Comment: Is there an easy way to export all the data from BigQuery? i.e. if I'm a user that is in marketing or PR will I be able to figure it out? Our biggest concern is that once we turn this over to the client they will not be able to figure out how to use BigQuery without using some expensive 3rd part front end.

Comment: Google Data Studio is a great front end for building and sharing charts and graphs easily.  It has a connector for BigQuery.  They just announced a free tier, too.

Comment: @SteveGanem How can I export user's data like location details to bigquery and how I will be able to see the geographic location (area/city/state) of each user through firebase console ?

Comment: Is there any way to get the csv via api?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about exporting data, not reports. I'm particularly interested in an API for doing this. So far, that doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: We need **raw event export**. What event was triggered by what user. I can do this so easily with Mixpanel the competitor it has even a built in JQL board for this. It is very useful when you are tracking down reported glitches for a particular user. Or when you need to understand one particular journey. Seems like analytics was never really tested with real users...

Answer (score 4):

As our company uses AWS for it's projects, BigQuery is not an option for now so I have moved on to **scrape** the data from Firebase.

You can use Selenium and Beautifulsoup in python to **scrape** the data from Firebase.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'to scrap' means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily select and copy UI blocks on the Analytics web page in Firebase, and then just paste the copied data into an Excel sheet. You'll see fancy tables.

There is a YouTube video that explains and demonstrates the procedure here:
[Copy Your Analytics Data to a Spreadsheet with this One WEIRD Trick! - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWJxxT6L1qA)

Comment: Not working for me today at June 2019, maybe they changed it.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Instead, there's a download button on the page itself which you can use to download said data on each event

Answer (score 0):

For all those who use AWS and want an automated pipeline, BigQuery allows you to export CSV if you have no arrays and JSON if you do. You can then automate exports to google cloud storage. Finally, you can use Airflow with AWS or an EC2 with a CRON or some other orchestration or scheduling system to schedule the merging of the google data to your AWS pipeline.