# Is it possible to embed a specific chart/KPI from Firebase Analytics into my website?

Tags: javascript, firebase, charts, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have a Firebase project which is initialized to capture some analytics from a mobile app.

I would like to get a specific chart from Analytics and embed it in my back-end website. Is this possible ? If not, Is it possible to create a live database from the Analytics in real time and access this database from my website ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API to get the charts from the Google Analytics for Firebase console into your own web site. See [How to export Firebase analytics data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689485/how-to-export-firebase-analytics-data).

The simplest two workarounds are:

1. To export the data from the Firebase console to CSV, by clicking on the <kbd>⠇</kbd> overflow menu in the top right and clicking <kbd>Download CSV</kbd>.
2. Connect your Firebase analytics data to BigQuery, so you can directly query it from your own web site.

Comment: FTR, linking to BigQuery will require paying for the account, if you're using a free tier. Thanks anyway