# How to export csv data from BigQuery of firebase(include record type)

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

The Firebase data includes record(struct) type. It can only export JSON data, but I need to export the csv data. I think I want to convert record(struct) type to string type for exporting csv data. How to do it?

Comment: Can you add data example an what's different in your questions from similar one like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37689485/1031958). Are you OK with the UI option and just want to see how to convert data or looking for other options.

Comment: It's different. BigQuery don't supports export csv data when the data include record(struct) field. I think may be have some syntax to convert to string value for record(struct) field

Comment: Please update your question with data example and expected output